# How to iterate over a column, while also conditioning another column?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I'm iterating over a column of a pandas dataframe and want built in a condition that is also dependent from another column.

Dataframe: df_a looks like this:

```
    name abb  POS_X  POS_Y  Q  Max Q
0      A   A   15.6   19.4  0      2
1    A-x   A   12.6   19.4  1      2
2   A-y2   A   18.6   19.4  2      2
3      B   B   15.0   25.0  0      2
4    B-a   B   12.0   25.0  1      2
5    B-d   B   18.0   25.0  2      2
6      C   C   15.0   10.0  0      3
7   C-x1   C   12.0   10.0  1      3
8   C-c4   C   18.0   10.0  2      3
9   C-a    C   11.0   10.0  3      3
```

Now I iterate over the index of the df and have a if-statement, the problem is with the elif-statement.

I want to say: do something if Q is unequal 0 and if POS_X is greater than POS_X when Q was 0.

```
for idx in df_a.index:

    if df_left['Q'][idx] == 0:

        do something
    
    elif df_a['Q'][idx] != 0 and df_a['POS_X'][idx] > df_a['POS_X'][idx] when df_a['Q'][idx] == 0:

        do something
   
    else:

        do something
```

I hope my desired condition is understandable. This condition shall be so often asked, until Q gets back to 0.

Comment: Please could you be more explicit in your "do something"? Iterating over indexes in pandas dataframes is not a good practice, and there is probably a built in pandas function that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you want but I think [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will get you there.

```
df["conditional"] = np.where(df["Q"].eq(0) | df["Q"].ne(0) & df["POS_X"].gt(df["POS_Y"]), "Do This", "Do That")
```

If you really have 2 seperate conditionals .

```
df["conditional"] = np.where(df["Q"].eq(0), "Do This", "Do That")
df["conditional2"] = np.where(df["Q"].ne(0) & df["POS_X"].gt(df["POS_Y"]), "Do This", "Do That")
```